# How to show only the outline of a bar plot matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm plotting data as a bar plot in **matplotlib** and am trying to only show the outline of the bars, so that it appears as a 'stepped graph' of the data.

I've added my code below along with an image of the desired output.

`plt.bar(x, y, align='center', width=0.1, edgecolor='black', color='none')`

### The plot I have:

[image: Current Plot]

### The plot I would like:

[image]

---

Are there any other libraries that may be able to produce this? The *bar* keyword arguments don't seem to have anything that can.

Comment: would a step plot work? https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.step.html

Comment: @AsishM. Yes this works perfectly, thank you! I should've known matplotlib would have a function for this... *facepalms*

Comment: Matplotlib's [stairs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html) plot is also a good option for this ([better than step in many cases](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/whats_new.html#new-stairs-method-and-steppatch-artist)).

Answer (score 2):

Your image looks like a function that is horizontal around each x,y value. The following code simulates this:

- for every x,y: create two new points one at x-0.5 and one at x+0.5, both with the same y
- to close the shape at the ends, add (x[0]-0.5, 0) at the start and (x[-1]+0.5, 0) at the end.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 30, 1)
y = np.random.uniform(2, 10, 30)
xs = [x[0] - 0.5]
ys = [0]
for i in range(len(x)):
    xs.append(x[i] - 0.5)
    xs.append(x[i] + 0.5)
    ys.append(y[i])
    ys.append(y[i])
xs.append(x[-1] + 0.5)
ys.append(0)
plt.plot(xs, ys, color='dodgerblue')
# optionally color the area below the curve
plt.fill_between(xs, 0, ys, color='gold')
```

PS: @AsishM. mentioned in the comments that matplotlib also has its own step function. If that function fulfils, please use that one. If you need some extra control or variation, this answer could give a start, such as coloring the area below the curve or handling the shape at the ends.

[image: example plot]

Comment: That's actually an awesome hack but Asish recommended the step function in matplotlib which solves the problem!

Comment: Didn't know about that step function, so I designed my own...  Maybe this gives a little extra flexibility and control, especially at the end points.